# Is START_STICKY useful if the app is force-closed by the user

Tags: android, service, forceclose

for my android app I want that users should not be allowed to kill it. The app has a service running that waits continuously for event notifications and currently if the user goes to the task manager he can force close the app and kill the service.

I read about START_STICKY but I am not sure what it does exactly...and when. If the app is automatically killed(low memory ??), does START_STICKY ensure that the service is restarted so the app will function normally again?

If that is indeed the case, can I use START_STICKY  to restart the service even if the user force closes it?

or is there any other way to prevent the user from closing the app???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know, START_ STICKY is useful if your are implementing a service that uses a server socket for **socket programming**.  Sometimes Android OS may, under low memory circumstances, kill background services so that memory may be reclaimed.  So if you use START_ STICKY then the service **will not be considered for reclaiming**.

Comment: so you mean to say that the START_STICKY is taken into consideration only when the OS has to choose a process to kill. If the user is killing the app, then using or not using START_STICKY makes no difference and the service will not be restarted at all?

Comment: if service is kill by os for low memory then it will restarted if you use START_STICKY

Comment: and not if the user explicitly kills it, right? sorry for asking again and again..but just need to confirm! thanks a lot for the answer! :)